# How do I get more focus?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I was looking at [How does focus work in dragon age inquisition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/how-does-focus-work-in-dragon-age-inquisition) but this doesn't exactly answer what I'm wondering. Right now I seem to cap out at one whole focus bar. At that point I can use my ability. I know there are more abilities via perks, but what do I need to do to be able to actually gather more focus beyond the first bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start out capped at one focus bar to fill up. The other two are unlocked by acquiring the Perks *Advanced Focus* and *Master Focus*. You will then be able to fill up the second and then the third focus bar, which will trigger the second- and third-tier effects, depending on how many bars are full.

In order to unlock *Advanced Focus* you need to have acquired 4 Perks in *Forces*. *Master Focus* is only available after having acquired *Advanced Focus*.